# JQuery slideshow script - click and drag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a slideshow script that allows the user to go to the next slide by clicking the current slide, and dragging it to the left - just like turning the page in a book.

I am wondering if a plugin already exists, and if someone can recommend one to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try **[Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)**. It has Hardware accelerated touch swipe support, or you may try **[PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/)**

In addition to this, have a look at **[5 Awesome Responsive jQuery Sliders and Image Galleries](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/responsive-jquery-sliders-image-galleries/)**